# Need help in creating LSTM network in tensorflow

Tags: lstm

I am pretty new in python and have gone through the few blogs and github codes but still can't figure out how to create a test and training set for LSTm model.

I have 176 X 20 features to Predict the wind speed (Y).  Can anyone help

time    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 Y
7/1/2002    15.82   2.71    0.02    121.67  0.26    8.60    7.12    8.97    847.00  833.60  833.10  284.77  283.04  282.37  93.00   62.00   0.06    1.50    1.58    0.79    16.903226
8/1/2002    11.59   2.79    0.01    127.69  0.36    24.80   22.95   24.66   812.30  825.70  852.80  284.19  283.62  283.72  432.00  252.00  0.09    1.54    1.80    0.90    17.870968
9/1/2002    11.22   2.90    0.02    132.65  0.30    13.24   2.64    15.56   891.80  882.80  877.10  290.91  288.88  288.02  49.00   128.00  0.05    1.48    1.96    1.17    23.333333
10/1/2002   4.40    3.37    0.12    139.15  0.40    11.04   4.29    11.67   893.20  873.80  852.60  291.95  288.61  286.30  38.00   81.00   0.12    1.24    2.35    1.41    25.967742
11/1/2002   3.79    3.20    0.06    142.21  0.46    13.83   34.68   13.80   924.80  908.00  892.40  296.03  291.33  288.37  168.00  99.00   0.11    1.17    2.69    1.38    27.266667
12/1/2002   7.16    3.08    0.14    140.61  0.61    10.02   8.28    11.20   742.00  660.70  670.00  281.73  272.17  272.35  184.00  101.00  0.28    0.54    3.51    1.71    24.935484
1/1/2003    13.51   2.49    0.17    141.84  0.71    13.14   12.74   13.32   626.00  627.20  608.40  272.10  271.68  269.22  262.00  128.00  0.16    0.99    3.24    1.77    21.967742
2/1/2003    19.08   1.99    0.15    138.48  0.82    13.85   16.50   11.77   617.90  532.10  472.60  268.83  259.65  252.11  321.00  136.00  0.15    0.83    4.27    2.24    20.750000
3/1/2003    44.86   2.12    0.05    135.29  0.63    11.42   11.33   11.34   700.60  685.30  697.10  276.49  273.78  273.18  260.00  129.00  0.09    0.92    3.54    2.02    20.193548
4/1/2003    38.00   2.14    0.01    129.60  0.44    17.15   28.77   15.52   812.50  836.20  864.10  286.83  287.42  288.23  647.00  184.00  0.10    1.30    3.38    1.72    19.133333
5/1/2003    27.25   2.19    0.01    123.81  0.45    10.44   6.61    11.39   744.70  731.50  758.00  278.59  276.56  276.94  137.00  94.00   0.06    1.46    2.40    1.15    15.741935
6/1/2003    26.29   2.03    0.02    121.60  0.43    17.75   4.51    18.63   828.10  795.40  789.00  284.94  281.32  279.93  61.00   174.00  0.07    1.49    2.48    1.49    15.100000
7/1/2003    25.36   2.68    0.01    121.94  0.24    13.43   4.50    13.43   896.20  879.70  878.60  288.33  285.87  284.68  62.00   138.00  0.05    1.47    1.79    0.95    16.935484
8/1/2003    23.61   2.26    0.02    126.75  0.44    13.51   7.96    13.84   875.30  877.00  856.20  288.33  286.34  283.60  56.00   106.00  0.11    1.36    2.19    1.21    19.129032
9/1/2003    17.49   2.76    0.01    133.61  0.29    11.99   0.70    12.07   904.10  897.40  894.60  292.32  288.51  287.55  10.00   92.00   0.06    1.33    2.10    1.08    23.633333
10/1/2003   6.77    3.03    0.06    138.59  0.66    19.27   18.04   19.05   837.00  784.20  773.00  290.07  283.50  281.61  425.00  129.00  0.14    1.01    2.86    1.44    24.129032
11/1/2003   6.45    3.30    0.10    142.74  0.62    15.08   3.72    17.93   781.80  794.00  812.50  284.07  282.56  282.88  41.00   135.00  0.15    0.90    3.12    1.66    26.300000
12/1/2003   13.41   2.87    0.10    142.68  0.57    16.64   17.16   16.30   668.60  664.60  700.10  274.40  273.84  278.03  333.00  163.00  0.17    0.94    3.93    2.06    23.677419
1/1/2004    20.18   2.23    0.15    143.54  0.77    20.00   26.13   13.83   620.20  567.80  515.90  270.24  264.66  259.41  563.00  153.00  0.12    0.92    4.59    2.53    21.322581
2/1/2004    35.01   2.26    0.12    136.89  0.69    15.50   15.90   15.07   570.30  548.60  543.30  264.04  259.78  257.28  307.00  168.00  0.08    1.35    4.21    2.44    20.172414
3/1/2004    47.16   2.49    0.09    135.53  0.57    14.40   7.56    17.66   680.00  669.40  703.60  275.74  272.55  274.08  99.00   192.00  0.05    1.46    3.33    1.99    20.064516
4/1/2004    34.77   2.57    0.04    129.58  0.42    15.73   10.85   17.37   752.00  770.30  809.40  280.31  280.30  281.45  179.00  214.00  0.06    1.39    2.76    1.67    17.400000
5/1/2004    34.11   2.00    0.03    123.70  0.51    13.96   4.38    15.10   733.00  731.40  740.50  279.25  277.73  276.51  76.00   150.00  0.06    1.40    3.14    1.92    15.354839
6/1/2004    30.93   2.48    0.01    121.05  0.21    14.32   4.37    14.32   900.50  893.50  897.40  289.93  287.75  286.85  82.00   144.00  0.04    1.50    1.74    1.11    16.133333
7/1/2004    24.46   2.15    0.02    121.77  0.29    16.14   0.84    16.24   885.90  871.20  868.70  287.75  285.44  284.46  21.00   139.00  0.04    1.49    2.01    1.25    16.903226
8/1/2004    22.54   2.11    0.01    127.26  0.19    16.43   2.58    16.81   899.30  886.10  895.80  289.62  286.82  286.38  23.00   138.00  0.07    1.31    1.55    0.88    20.967742
9/1/2004    13.22   2.61    0.03    133.75  0.40    25.25   22.89   25.17   884.20  854.70  878.40  290.26  285.06  285.21  195.00  200.00  0.06    1.37    2.05    1.40    21.500000
10/1/2004   6.00    2.89    0.06    138.19  0.50    15.01   10.44   15.08   872.20  845.90  833.50  291.33  287.92  286.43  218.00  139.00  0.11    1.20    2.80    1.68    25.032258
11/1/2004   6.11    3.10    0.10    142.54  0.64    13.56   5.40    16.58   788.40  727.30  708.70  284.94  278.15  275.57  63.00   134.00  0.15    1.23    3.57    1.68    24.333333
12/1/2004   11.95   2.54    0.11    141.30  0.70    16.99   16.34   16.96   686.00  630.20  617.50  277.49  271.75  269.83  343.00  172.00  0.17    1.09    4.08    1.99    23.096774
1/1/2005    25.49   2.39    0.10    141.14  0.78    22.53   25.98   18.56   611.40  589.00  547.20  268.82  264.93  259.21  494.00  210.00  0.08    1.11    3.82    2.28    21.032258
2/1/2005    56.12   2.19    0.10    139.35  0.50    14.55   14.47   14.60   761.20  732.60  722.00  283.34  280.32  278.48  242.00  151.00  0.06    1.34    3.71    2.21    24.928571
3/1/2005    44.12   2.44    0.07    134.12  0.64    8.63    5.01    13.73   545.50  562.70  616.00  261.14  262.54  266.37  89.00   161.00  0.07    1.22    3.34    1.72    19.709677
4/1/2005    32.64   2.74    0.01    128.99  0.36    15.26   3.14    16.14   806.50  817.80  855.80  285.32  284.87  285.61  50.00   184.00  0.05    1.39    2.58    1.71    19.500000
5/1/2005    23.52   2.05    0.00    123.92  0.26    8.16    2.13    10.75   800.40  787.70  819.30  281.69  279.96  282.13  32.00   95.00   0.04    1.41    1.90    1.07    17.709677
6/1/2005    13.15   2.46    0.03    121.23  0.64    18.52   13.69   18.69   806.60  756.90  732.80  283.92  278.90  275.47  85.00   159.00  0.05    1.50    2.94    1.92    13.166667
7/1/2005    14.94   2.82    0.02    122.73  0.37    22.33   31.64   21.20   833.60  799.40  799.80  284.97  281.81  280.94  827.00  196.00  0.04    1.50    1.96    1.34    15.354839
8/1/2005    23.62   2.72    0.02    126.23  0.42    22.77   28.20   21.90   792.00  789.20  813.60  281.27  280.29  280.79  375.00  212.00  0.08    1.50    1.82    0.91    17.096774
9/1/2005    22.26   2.42    0.02    134.10  0.38    14.99   5.79    19.70   851.20  851.30  861.80  286.43  284.48  285.22  122.00  170.00  0.04    1.48    2.27    1.12    22.266667
10/1/2005   10.01   2.74    0.09    138.87  0.61    14.94   19.97   12.90   788.40  782.40  753.70  284.22  282.27  279.32  360.00  111.00  0.10    1.37    3.44    1.82    24.096774
11/1/2005   11.60   2.91    0.11    142.66  0.56    13.86   14.23   13.30   817.20  790.20  750.80  288.34  285.05  280.63  214.00  123.00  0.15    1.14    3.80    1.85    24.900000
12/1/2005   16.18   2.79    0.11    143.47  0.44    11.67   7.56    16.07   803.40  726.90  717.30  288.15  279.52  277.36  139.00  151.00  0.17    0.93    3.82    1.82    26.258065
1/1/2006    25.18   2.74    0.11    139.70  0.67    15.17   17.78   13.00   645.00  581.20  536.00  274.17  265.80  259.71  366.00  163.00  0.12    0.83    3.93    2.11    20.709677
2/1/2006    46.64   2.39    0.12    139.28  0.42    9.77    5.93    11.36   835.70  805.70  770.70  290.65  287.10  281.92  112.00  124.00  0.08    1.16    4.27    2.42    24.464286
3/1/2006    34.34   2.71    0.13    134.36  0.71    14.56   12.94   15.27   656.40  617.70  600.30  272.39  267.12  263.73  246.00  172.00  0.10    0.87    3.68    2.26    18.096774
4/1/2006    24.53   2.50    0.09    129.42  0.82    15.97   11.24   19.43   554.00  498.40  503.50  262.16  255.78  254.19  202.00  204.00  0.09    1.30    3.94    2.24    14.000000
5/1/2006    27.17   2.41    0.09    124.91  0.68    18.46   8.60    20.17   710.70  681.60  692.00  276.13  272.67  272.49  128.00  215.00  0.03    1.50    2.99    1.69    12.903226
6/1/2006    25.98   2.93    0.04    121.56  0.48    19.05   3.81    20.36   787.20  779.40  761.00  280.22  278.22  274.87  44.00   219.00  0.36    1.50    2.20    1.76    13.133333
7/1/2006    27.50   2.25    0.02    121.88  0.39    19.03   11.10   19.10   834.60  827.80  811.70  284.75  283.09  280.80  209.00  239.00  0.03    1.50    1.89    1.58    15.096774
8/1/2006    36.45   2.28    0.00    126.05  0.14    13.09   3.37    13.33   909.70  908.50  916.20  289.76  288.07  287.14  34.00   92.00   0.05    1.49    1.52    0.67    20.612903
9/1/2006    24.30   2.67    0.02    133.25  0.40    22.56   27.49   22.44   862.60  868.90  879.50  288.53  286.35  285.72  434.00  255.00  0.02    1.50    2.10    1.43    21.333333
10/1/2006   11.30   2.99    0.06    140.08  0.46    25.13   21.56   25.21   896.90  900.80  910.00  291.55  288.76  287.93  171.00  299.00  0.05    1.46    2.47    1.55    24.387097
11/1/2006   11.30   2.85    0.08    142.08  0.38    10.82   5.09    10.98   888.50  879.00  877.30  293.48  290.28  288.67  101.00  91.00   0.08    1.25    2.68    1.55    26.300000
12/1/2006   11.53   2.90    0.16    140.89  0.66    18.45   7.95    19.44   787.60  747.60  730.10  285.60  280.88  278.49  119.00  181.00  0.13    0.65    3.65    2.03    23.354839
1/1/2007    16.66   2.52    0.15    140.37  0.90    13.78   16.06   12.29   585.80  527.70  475.90  268.30  260.29  253.73  321.00  142.00  0.17    0.36    4.48    2.34    19.774194
2/1/2007    25.09   2.95    0.04    138.16  0.77    20.04   23.99   16.76   524.50  498.20  489.70  262.40  257.46  255.20  415.00  206.00  0.04    1.49    3.92    2.37    16.571429
3/1/2007    41.93   2.02    0.08    135.82  0.58    13.01   5.51    16.03   741.50  707.50  702.10  280.64  276.85  276.21  121.00  174.00  0.06    1.39    3.79    2.25    20.419355
4/1/2007    40.94   2.45    0.05    129.71  0.32    13.52   5.42    16.56   782.80  812.90  851.60  282.10  283.44  285.97  56.00   166.00  0.04    1.50    2.91    1.24    19.800000
5/1/2007    31.02   2.43    0.05    124.02  0.43    13.44   4.69    14.67   772.50  787.90  822.70  280.60  280.65  282.30  82.00   159.00  0.03    1.50    3.19    1.86    16.645161
6/1/2007    12.23   2.69    0.02    121.30  0.67    27.01   21.31   27.77   639.70  661.10  656.70  270.80  272.66  272.42  421.00  284.00  0.02    1.50    1.55    1.80    10.833333
7/1/2007    31.07   2.20    0.01    121.69  0.22    13.12   0.73    14.11   834.20  841.30  847.20  281.06  281.70  282.03  14.00   152.00  0.02    1.50    1.38    1.08    17.580645
8/1/2007    27.24   2.60    0.01    127.29  0.46    19.12   20.56   18.85   796.70  806.20  794.40  282.88  282.46  280.78  328.00  192.00  0.23    1.51    2.20    0.93    17.451613
9/1/2007    25.14   2.36    0.06    133.58  0.32    22.68   42.01   12.01   867.90  874.90  880.90  289.07  287.40  287.12  738.00  93.00   0.05    1.48    2.21    0.86    22.566667
10/1/2007   11.49   3.08    0.05    138.29  0.60    13.39   1.82    14.13   824.40  810.90  801.50  288.68  285.29  283.67  35.00   132.00  0.06    1.48    2.95    1.31    24.322581
11/1/2007   9.98    3.22    0.12    141.61  0.80    17.76   12.16   18.30   829.70  750.70  703.50  288.51  280.90  276.76  125.00  151.00  0.08    1.30    3.55    2.12    23.000000
12/1/2007   16.32   2.73    0.10    141.12  0.68    13.26   13.22   13.27   680.30  640.20  602.00  275.56  269.60  264.87  255.00  133.00  0.11    1.16    4.21    2.41    21.774194
1/1/2008    28.03   2.27    0.09    141.34  0.77    16.57   17.20   15.01   520.90  476.80  469.30  256.25  252.33  251.62  348.00  161.00  0.06    1.19    4.21    1.92    19.709677
2/1/2008    31.08   2.43    0.08    138.13  0.84    21.56   22.33   20.21   451.20  472.70  478.20  250.65  252.12  250.21  434.00  236.00  0.02    1.50    4.33    2.22    17.068966
3/1/2008    38.80   2.69    0.10    136.10  0.66    15.67   15.57   15.71   731.70  739.80  730.20  279.22  278.62  276.53  261.00  164.00  0.02    1.50    3.64    2.16    18.870968
4/1/2008    44.43   2.13    0.04    128.77  0.42    7.98    3.68    11.43   730.00  723.40  766.10  276.49  275.16  278.21  66.00   90.00   0.04    1.50    2.32    0.99    20.133333
5/1/2008    29.93   2.56    0.03    124.34  0.46    12.74   5.30    18.41   648.30  685.00  736.20  268.01  270.60  274.15  68.00   174.00  0.02    1.50    1.88    0.78    16.645161
6/1/2008    23.32   2.50    0.03    121.47  0.33    11.84   6.97    12.80   802.60  815.00  829.60  282.01  282.20  282.26  125.00  104.00  0.03    1.50    2.22    1.18    14.366667
7/1/2008    19.19   2.32    0.01    121.75  0.42    26.60   21.22   27.12   756.70  773.50  790.50  277.86  278.60  279.87  399.00  278.00  0.03    1.50    1.62    1.17    14.677419
8/1/2008    27.28   2.44    0.02    127.81  0.39    12.12   4.44    13.64   787.90  781.00  812.90  278.87  278.55  281.33  47.00   96.00   0.05    1.50    1.86    1.27    18.580645
9/1/2008    20.12   2.56    0.01    132.75  0.55    22.38   30.01   21.21   886.30  863.30  836.20  290.34  287.00  284.60  767.00  186.00  0.04    1.50    2.77    1.74    20.200000
10/1/2008   10.55   3.23    0.07    139.18  0.55    12.31   1.89    12.57   883.80  888.30  882.40  291.44  289.22  287.22  29.00   113.00  0.06    1.49    2.77    1.64    23.838710
11/1/2008   9.55    2.82    0.07    142.18  0.62    13.34   13.42   12.93   688.40  662.00  681.70  274.97  271.60  272.40  243.00  106.00  0.07    1.36    3.19    1.71    22.933333
12/1/2008   16.76   2.68    0.10    139.99  0.61    12.46   8.35    14.48   734.90  667.70  646.20  281.23  273.74  269.80  170.00  147.00  0.09    1.20    4.36    2.29    23.645161
1/1/2009    15.29   2.84    0.13    142.85  0.98    21.55   26.81   14.54   442.30  394.60  349.20  252.36  245.96  240.75  544.00  184.00  0.09    1.23    5.63    2.33    14.870968
2/1/2009    26.68   2.65    0.14    138.41  0.83    19.22   22.30   15.68   502.70  462.70  426.30  258.11  252.91  247.10  455.00  197.00  0.02    1.50    3.82    2.20    16.142857
3/1/2009    48.98   2.31    0.08    135.10  0.58    10.27   9.46    10.97   661.50  660.00  662.20  270.28  269.80  269.18  169.00  116.00  0.03    1.50    3.36    1.86    20.870968
4/1/2009    37.26   2.02    0.07    129.44  0.62    12.48   5.30    15.35   756.60  727.70  648.40  280.82  276.24  267.07  107.00  193.00  0.03    1.49    3.10    2.07    18.733333
5/1/2009    24.71   2.39    0.06    123.73  0.63    13.31   7.55    15.63   609.10  620.30  658.60  265.48  267.03  270.19  96.00   159.00  0.03    1.50    2.37    1.33    14.322581
6/1/2009    27.54   1.94    0.05    121.68  0.35    11.88   5.04    13.03   843.50  792.10  791.50  284.08  278.66  278.29  42.00   122.00  0.04    1.50    2.03    1.26    16.366667
7/1/2009    22.44   2.39    0.02    122.06  0.22    11.50   1.63    12.21   843.40  844.90  857.30  283.03  283.28  284.96  19.00   92.00   0.03    1.50    1.85    0.79    17.451613
8/1/2009    19.31   2.35    0.01    126.88  0.18    13.23   2.25    13.23   929.50  914.30  917.10  292.93  289.93  289.35  25.00   100.00  0.05    1.50    2.12    0.89    20.129032
9/1/2009    11.74   2.48    0.09    133.69  0.29    11.85   4.54    11.89   936.60  903.90  900.30  295.06  290.81  289.41  23.00   78.00   0.13    1.28    2.06    1.22    23.100000
10/1/2009   4.87    3.10    0.12    138.68  0.54    16.32   4.08    16.33   890.80  847.00  843.20  292.83  287.15  285.35  29.00   135.00  0.11    1.36    2.51    1.40    25.096774
11/1/2009   6.83    3.18    0.06    141.64  0.46    15.28   11.54   16.39   821.20  804.90  806.20  286.96  283.87  283.42  183.00  163.00  0.06    1.38    2.86    1.62    24.033333
12/1/2009   8.01    2.88    0.09    142.85  0.55    15.35   13.90   15.57   765.50  734.60  724.40  284.21  279.67  276.71  288.00  171.00  0.16    0.86    3.28    1.85    24.612903
1/1/2010    15.78   3.02    0.12    140.65  0.77    19.15   23.59   11.74   523.80  514.00  483.30  259.05  257.20  253.26  466.00  130.00  0.08    1.07    4.19    2.05    17.645161
2/1/2010    32.60   2.18    0.08    139.12  0.79    20.39   26.87   10.55   574.30  528.50  495.50  264.59  258.58  253.88  524.00  130.00  0.04    1.50    4.43    2.26    18.821429
3/1/2010    31.73   3.02    0.13    134.03  0.68    13.64   6.78    18.19   595.60  609.70  628.60  266.42  266.72  266.59  119.00  219.00  0.03    1.50    3.93    1.96    17.258065
4/1/2010    30.20   2.55    0.08    129.84  0.69    15.55   7.76    18.59   642.20  633.00  643.10  271.26  269.77  270.86  157.00  215.00  0.03    1.50    3.71    2.07    15.000000
5/1/2010    34.35   2.38    0.05    124.12  0.50    11.59   2.19    12.62   747.50  710.40  715.30  279.39  275.29  274.90  30.00   121.00  0.02    1.50    2.74    1.54    16.032258
6/1/2010    25.39   2.49    0.05    120.98  0.38    16.18   28.18   15.47   862.10  821.10  802.50  286.65  282.58  280.57  262.00  124.00  0.02    1.50    2.41    1.54    15.566667
7/1/2010    20.27   2.59    0.07    122.49  0.54    16.44   7.25    17.24   785.60  785.10  789.00  281.71  281.24  281.43  65.00   151.00  0.05    1.50    2.67    1.97    13.225806
8/1/2010    24.46   2.57    0.03    126.37  0.57    17.98   8.21    18.28   863.20  815.20  806.10  287.28  282.99  281.68  73.00   169.00  0.03    1.50    2.26    2.05    16.290323
9/1/2010    18.65   2.68    0.07    133.53  0.75    17.62   16.03   17.99   793.10  786.10  777.70  283.64  282.23  280.69  258.00  149.00  0.02    1.50    3.63    2.19    18.000000
10/1/2010   14.37   2.91    0.02    140.20  0.75    15.68   6.41    17.21   718.20  725.00  733.50  278.90  277.75  277.57  110.00  177.00  0.04    1.47    3.04    1.73    20.774194
11/1/2010   11.70   2.67    0.16    141.13  0.90    21.64   21.88   21.28   596.20  574.00  563.70  268.13  264.57  262.89  458.00  227.00  0.06    1.48    3.87    1.82    16.966667
12/1/2010   15.94   2.43    0.08    142.01  0.84    18.17   19.29   15.06   437.30  431.40  454.30  247.42  245.73  246.68  374.00  177.00  0.02    1.50    4.79    1.78    17.741935
1/1/2011    37.40   2.09    0.12    140.24  0.61    15.13   17.29   13.28   646.90  620.40  652.90  272.60  268.30  270.08  327.00  163.00  0.02    1.50    4.06    2.33    21.774194
2/1/2011    33.32   2.91    0.15    139.50  0.76    15.55   16.18   13.94   515.30  523.30  518.60  257.79  258.33  256.88  298.00  180.00  0.03    1.50    4.45    2.11    19.142857
3/1/2011    25.89   2.44    0.19    134.59  0.95    17.43   16.57   17.96   473.70  465.40  479.20  257.79  256.17  257.43  346.00  229.00  0.08    1.50    5.28    2.28    14.483871
4/1/2011    36.95   2.48    0.10    129.16  0.54    18.49   11.05   20.31   745.10  732.80  739.20  279.63  277.54  276.08  170.00  218.00  0.03    1.50    2.81    1.71    16.800000
5/1/2011    34.19   2.82    0.06    124.67  0.24    15.20   1.56    15.30   878.60  866.60  861.10  288.33  286.17  285.08  29.00   166.00  0.02    1.50    1.88    1.73    16.870968
6/1/2011    25.03   2.95    0.04    121.60  0.36    22.73   3.85    24.36   807.90  802.30  798.10  280.81  281.12  280.50  43.00   236.00  0.02    1.50    1.42    1.39    14.866667
7/1/2011    25.58   2.67    0.05    121.64  0.27    16.75   6.17    19.04   842.60  801.70  806.90  282.34  279.29  279.67  160.00  157.00  0.04    1.50    1.64    1.13    17.096774
8/1/2011    23.18   3.09    0.03    127.68  0.30    17.17   15.34   17.17   891.30  862.40  854.00  288.81  285.82  284.28  87.00   133.00  0.04    1.50    1.61    1.00    18.870968
9/1/2011    16.30   3.25    0.09    132.86  0.36    13.86   3.68    14.95   882.10  856.00  848.20  287.33  284.93  284.16  31.00   117.00  0.08    1.46    1.90    0.81    22.500000
10/1/2011   7.58    3.41    0.15    139.41  0.66    22.73   21.57   22.62   755.40  738.60  732.40  279.84  278.09  277.40  466.00  181.00  0.14    1.47    2.91    1.53    22.161290
11/1/2011   9.67    4.02    0.07    142.27  0.65    11.15   9.54    12.04   768.90  761.60  770.10  282.36  280.22  279.84  206.00  118.00  0.08    1.52    3.29    1.68    23.900000
12/1/2011   16.49   3.29    0.22    140.49  0.73    15.95   16.26   15.27   606.70  587.90  569.60  267.71  265.34  262.70  301.00  136.00  0.12    1.33    3.84    1.59    21.161290
1/1/2012    25.46   2.86    0.17    142.00  0.72    13.29   12.83   13.78   643.20  558.30  511.50  270.01  259.90  254.13  245.00  142.00  0.16    1.39    4.15    2.05    21.516129
2/1/2012    47.76   2.87    0.07    137.86  0.71    10.65   8.75    14.28   576.60  571.10  557.40  263.12  262.17  259.72  171.00  173.00  0.02    1.50    4.25    1.94    20.689655
3/1/2012    41.18   3.27    0.10    134.28  0.77    16.14   13.83   18.16   584.80  562.80  535.80  264.55  261.12  257.11  258.00  192.00  0.03    1.50    3.63    2.00    15.580645
4/1/2012    44.01   2.71    0.07    129.40  0.45    14.22   5.73    16.93   732.00  738.20  759.00  277.05  276.77  277.08  57.00   153.00  0.03    1.50    2.83    1.60    18.433333
5/1/2012    27.96   3.30    0.04    124.84  0.52    20.20   14.42   21.99   727.10  678.90  663.60  276.67  271.76  268.92  263.00  242.00  0.02    1.50    2.16    1.05    14.419355
6/1/2012    27.92   2.49    0.04    121.65  0.30    15.38   12.98   15.52   819.90  844.00  861.70  283.20  284.24  285.33  291.00  180.00  0.02    1.50    1.70    1.56    14.466667
7/1/2012    25.80   3.02    0.03    122.63  0.42    20.57   12.15   20.61   840.60  786.30  778.10  284.75  280.15  279.05  110.00  221.00  0.02    1.50    1.85    1.89    14.483871
8/1/2012    33.48   2.35    0.03    126.67  0.34    13.82   21.81   13.39   897.60  886.90  871.30  287.96  286.88  285.22  318.00  126.00  0.04    1.50    1.83    1.53    19.193548
9/1/2012    25.86   3.04    0.04    133.35  0.48    20.77   2.58    23.55   826.10  798.80  793.40  283.33  281.40  280.87  42.00   169.00  0.03    1.50    2.23    0.83    22.133333
10/1/2012   11.25   3.56    0.05    141.31  0.48    9.91    3.95    12.57   819.20  775.70  766.40  284.26  280.63  280.09  71.00   90.00   0.04    1.50    2.24    1.12    24.419355
11/1/2012   11.30   3.70    0.07    142.17  0.51    14.80   7.65    15.49   853.80  824.40  809.90  290.46  286.55  284.29  169.00  114.00  0.10    1.49    3.11    1.42    25.066667
12/1/2012   15.45   3.36    0.17    140.91  0.61    21.39   29.26   13.95   790.30  735.80  703.80  286.04  279.95  276.19  734.00  116.00  0.21    1.40    3.66    1.79    24.774194
1/1/2013    30.25   3.63    0.04    140.39  0.50    20.95   30.62   11.22   692.60  650.00  623.10  276.53  270.46  266.23  580.00  119.00  0.08    1.42    3.65    2.15    22.709677
2/1/2013    46.20   2.62    0.10    138.30  0.63    12.54   8.36    13.41   767.80  718.10  641.90  284.39  279.36  271.03  104.00  143.00  0.05    1.31    3.75    2.39    22.071429
3/1/2013    44.97   2.92    0.07    135.77  0.68    9.70    5.97    12.52   664.50  623.80  592.20  271.12  266.65  262.53  103.00  155.00  0.04    1.48    3.48    2.07    19.935484
4/1/2013    36.46   2.87    0.06    129.57  0.60    19.55   18.84   19.34   737.40  746.70  763.70  279.16  279.71  280.30  353.00  219.00  0.04    1.50    3.49    1.93    17.233333
5/1/2013    27.30   3.28    0.09    123.95  0.54    14.66   12.79   14.81   781.40  756.30  739.00  282.09  279.06  276.28  106.00  157.00  0.04    1.50    2.76    1.93    14.225806
6/1/2013    28.81   2.55    0.05    121.28  0.33    15.05   5.10    15.26   816.20  770.90  776.50  283.84  279.27  279.68  109.00  159.00  0.03    1.50    2.41    1.29    15.300000
7/1/2013    21.74   3.53    0.03    121.87  0.38    16.55   5.89    16.57   838.90  822.70  807.80  285.87  283.76  281.92  108.00  165.00  0.05    1.46    2.32    1.30    14.903226
8/1/2013    27.32   2.34    0.01    127.53  0.24    16.43   1.50    16.48   923.60  888.70  882.10  291.00  287.24  286.06  6.00    137.00  0.06    1.50    1.91    0.85    20.354839
9/1/2013    17.42   3.31    0.05    133.85  0.34    12.21   1.52    12.21   882.20  887.70  878.10  290.77  289.87  288.78  6.00    107.00  0.06    1.48    2.21    0.77    22.800000
10/1/2013   6.90    3.52    0.04    138.54  0.49    11.45   2.83    12.90   900.20  859.50  871.00  292.80  288.48  288.55  24.00   113.00  0.08    1.43    2.96    1.58    24.774194
11/1/2013   5.99    3.36    0.06    141.77  0.77    14.37   12.54   14.90   676.50  630.70  619.10  275.18  270.12  268.15  245.00  151.00  0.06    1.34    3.20    1.51    22.300000
12/1/2013   14.86   3.68    0.06    141.12  0.41    8.21    3.20    13.10   779.40  752.30  788.60  283.60  280.35  283.64  54.00   107.00  0.12    1.10    3.25    1.34    25.935484
1/1/2014    15.69   3.95    0.12    141.41  0.75    22.26   36.87   12.98   624.70  549.70  503.00  270.45  263.20  258.57  606.00  131.00  0.17    1.20    4.45    1.96    21.387097
2/1/2014    36.62   3.41    0.16    139.46  0.66    18.15   23.75   15.00   630.30  630.50  635.30  269.83  269.33  268.72  483.00  168.00  0.09    1.21    3.67    2.06    19.535714
3/1/2014    41.98   3.18    0.07    134.47  0.66    13.33   10.86   14.41   711.90  661.50  622.40  276.51  270.33  265.19  151.00  176.00  0.05    1.41    3.57    2.12    17.580645
4/1/2014    38.75   2.92    0.09    129.27  0.52    13.17   12.81   13.43   720.20  692.90  697.70  276.34  272.05  271.58  197.00  143.00  0.04    1.50    3.25    1.66    17.100000
5/1/2014    32.33   3.00    0.05    123.87  0.45    16.03   19.76   14.55   751.50  766.10  757.20  277.61  278.42  277.43  447.00  171.00  0.03    1.50    2.59    1.52    16.161290
6/1/2014    28.75   2.88    0.04    121.33  0.46    19.38   16.79   21.29   717.10  735.50  740.90  273.74  275.30  275.90  306.00  228.00  0.03    1.50    2.25    1.34    13.566667
7/1/2014    29.38   2.53    0.02    123.02  0.27    11.16   6.04    11.92   859.20  837.90  843.90  284.28  283.09  283.47  77.00   98.00   0.03    1.50    1.58    0.87    17.000000
8/1/2014    27.88   2.97    0.03    126.45  0.31    17.65   7.82    17.60   883.80  875.30  885.90  287.35  285.40  285.13  61.00   149.00  0.06    1.50    1.77    1.23    19.161290
9/1/2014    23.17   2.76    0.02    133.17  0.34    12.25   2.99    16.51   857.10  876.10  891.20  286.32  286.29  286.73  55.00   144.00  0.03    1.50    2.12    1.02    22.566667
10/1/2014   10.48   3.44    0.04    138.39  0.43    20.61   32.01   19.76   901.50  894.80  913.80  292.27  289.16  290.01  732.00  169.00  0.05    1.48    2.33    1.23    25.774194
11/1/2014   8.84    3.62    0.06    141.88  0.43    7.00    4.55    9.79    815.00  793.30  831.50  285.59  282.79  286.02  74.00   95.00   0.10    1.15    3.12    1.44    26.066667
12/1/2014   12.52   3.26    0.08    142.62  0.61    11.12   11.87   10.89   797.30  706.00  654.50  287.14  277.63  271.26  194.00  96.00   0.15    1.00    3.95    1.84    25.290323
1/1/2015    24.20   2.81    0.09    139.72  0.81    19.96   24.52   13.61   524.40  498.70  506.70  257.51  254.14  254.39  439.00  154.00  0.10    1.33    4.52    2.45    20.870968
2/1/2015    45.79   3.07    0.11    140.05  0.80    8.72    4.28    11.68   647.80  608.40  576.50  271.30  266.41  262.00  60.00   122.00  0.05    1.43    3.90    2.17    21.857143
3/1/2015    41.56   3.14    0.05    134.32  0.48    7.06    5.91    8.47    745.40  711.90  717.30  279.36  275.54  275.71  111.00  85.00   0.08    1.29    3.88    2.17    21.774194
4/1/2015    26.66   2.66    0.05    129.63  0.47    11.86   1.92    13.81   727.80  780.40  817.10  278.27  281.81  284.76  25.00   151.00  0.05    1.49    2.89    1.70    19.900000
5/1/2015    15.70   2.60    0.04    125.00  0.33    14.01   5.83    14.39   858.90  845.70  831.80  288.65  286.22  284.09  56.00   133.00  0.05    1.48    2.30    1.56    17.290323
6/1/2015    13.85   2.95    0.08    120.29  0.48    15.85   3.85    16.60   784.80  782.50  802.90  281.90  280.70  281.32  54.00   172.00  0.06    1.50    2.50    1.44    12.966667
7/1/2015    14.89   2.62    0.03    123.63  0.38    15.93   22.05   15.91   878.20  845.10  847.30  287.37  283.48  282.64  462.00  119.00  0.06    1.49    2.01    1.33    16.612903
8/1/2015    13.79   2.49    0.03    127.24  0.31    15.31   1.04    15.59   891.70  899.30  907.50  288.33  287.93  287.66  12.00   124.00  0.09    1.27    1.92    1.26    20.290323
9/1/2015    7.89    2.99    0.06    133.41  0.43    19.15   36.98   18.76   864.90  889.20  908.60  289.20  288.34  287.69  1198.00 118.00  0.07    1.35    2.19    0.76    22.800000
10/1/2015   3.24    4.16    0.11    140.23  0.57    17.06   15.30   16.92   870.50  865.70  881.20  289.67  286.95  286.55  295.00  155.00  0.13    1.02    2.85    1.18    24.483871
11/1/2015   4.99    3.51    0.08    141.94  0.58    12.16   9.14    12.30   856.90  777.60  744.10  291.60  283.11  279.22  185.00  108.00  0.14    0.87    3.75    2.06    25.033333
12/1/2015   6.56    3.72    0.11    141.46  0.65    12.34   10.09   13.06   707.30  662.90  640.30  278.75  273.07  269.44  189.00  137.00  0.21    0.46    3.91    1.92    22.903226
1/1/2016    18.35   3.20    0.09    140.43  0.56    18.31   27.63   12.57   757.80  669.80  598.70  281.81  271.89  263.26  441.00  113.00  0.16    1.06    3.66    2.60    23.387097
2/1/2016    43.65   2.31    0.06    139.98  0.58    22.29   32.26   12.29   721.80  679.50  589.30  278.33  274.44  264.58  518.00  133.00  0.08    1.21    3.77    2.62    22.862069
3/1/2016    33.75   2.76    0.05    134.14  0.66    12.56   12.04   12.89   632.20  612.40  561.50  270.77  268.07  261.22  238.00  163.00  0.09    1.48    4.17    2.37    18.225806
4/1/2016    39.64   3.09    0.05    129.83  0.48    12.70   5.87    14.74   770.00  728.00  765.70  282.19  277.44  279.12  99.00   171.00  0.06    1.49    3.02    1.71    18.100000
5/1/2016    30.66   2.74    0.04    124.02  0.55    12.71   5.99    15.84   734.90  708.20  705.20  278.89  274.76  273.15  83.00   177.00  0.05    1.50    3.44    1.75    14.903226
6/1/2016    24.76   2.64    0.04    120.92  0.42    19.39   21.91   18.90   846.90  821.40  832.90  287.14  283.67  283.68  513.00  193.00  0.03    1.50    2.70    1.87    13.300000
7/1/2016    25.32   2.69    0.03    122.51  0.38    20.04   18.99   19.73   844.30  836.70  822.10  285.94  284.10  282.15  388.00  211.00  0.03    1.50    2.28    1.74    14.451613
8/1/2016    26.42   3.20    0.05    126.46  0.51    16.40   16.80   16.40   822.50  830.80  828.80  285.24  284.33  283.26  149.00  151.00  0.07    1.50    2.09    0.93    16.870968
9/1/2016    20.11   2.92    0.05    133.80  0.65    13.90   16.64   13.89   844.40  815.70  801.50  289.25  285.24  283.19  277.00  131.00  0.04    1.50    3.13    1.95    18.800000
10/1/2016   11.31   3.48    0.04    140.44  0.62    21.94   30.74   19.53   855.00  832.50  804.90  289.20  285.40  282.59  417.00  160.00  0.04    1.45    2.83    1.43    23.612903
11/1/2016   10.67   3.30    0.07    141.34  0.61    13.29   5.77    13.73   841.30  754.60  702.60  290.68  282.55  277.05  120.00  112.00  0.08    1.34    3.59    1.68    24.100000
12/1/2016   12.04   3.35    0.05    142.15  0.53    14.62   11.13   15.22   749.50  722.20  705.90  282.94  279.12  276.30  229.00  156.00  0.10    1.05    3.90    2.11    22.612903
1/1/2017    27.01   3.11    0.05    140.33  0.64    21.61   27.80   15.94   678.50  633.60  640.30  276.00  271.51  271.56  555.00  205.00  0.05    1.26    3.95    2.65    19.419355
2/1/2017    37.05   3.09    0.11    139.59  0.56    13.76   15.62   12.96   691.60  659.00  648.40  277.87  274.75  272.70  317.00  142.00  0.06    1.05    4.19    2.20    20.571429

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

import time
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.preprocessing as prep
df = pd.read_csv('DATA_ADL2.csv')
data_to_use = df['Y'].values


scaler = StandardScaler()

scaled_dataset = scaler.fit_transform(data_to_use.reshape(-1, 1))

def window_data(data, window_size):
X = []
y = []

i = 0
while (i + window_size) <= len(data) - 1:
    X.append(data[i:i+window_size])
    y.append(data[i+window_size])

    i += 1
assert len(X) ==  len(y)
return X, y
X, y = window_data(scaled_dataset, 27)
X_train  = np.array(X[:158])
y_train = np.array(y[:158])

X_test = np.array(X[158:])
y_test = np.array(y[158:])

print("X_train size: {}".format(X_train.shape))
print("y_train size: {}".format(y_train.shape))
print("X_test size: {}".format(X_test.shape))
print("y_test size: {}".format(y_test.shape))
```

coming as 
X_train size: (158, 27, 1)
y_train size: (158, 1)
X_test size: (1, 27, 1)
y_test size: (1, 1)

I need Xtrain 158,27,1
ytrain 158,1
x test 28,27
ytest 28,1